# Finding the probability distribution for the displacement of object 1 relative to object 2

Tags: calculus, probability-distributions, vectors

Displacement is similar to distance, but unlike distance displacement is a vector.  The displacement between two points can be expressed using the equation

$$\vec{r}=\vec{a_1}-\vec{a_2}$$ with $\vec{r}$ being the displacement between the two vectors $\vec{a_1}$, and $\vec{a_2}$. 
 So the norm of the displacement vector is the distance.

Let's say the position of object 1 is given as $(x_1,y_1)$ while the position of object 2 is given as $(x_2,y_2)$, and so the displacement of object 1 relative to object 2 is given as $(x_1-x_2,y_1-y_2)$.

Let's also say that the probability amplitude of object 1 as a function of position is given as $f(x_1,y_1)$, and the probability amplitude of object 2 as a function of position is given as $g(x_2,y_2)$.  Also the probability amplitude of the displacement of object 1 relative to object 2 is given as $h(x_1-x_2,y_1-y_2)$.

Given $f(x_1,y_1)$, and $g(x_2,y_2)$, how do I find $h(x_1-x_2,y_1-y_2)$?

Comment: What is a probability amplitude?

Answer (score 0):

The straightforward way to do it is to use the convolution:
$$
h(a,b) = \iint f(x,y)g(a-x,b-y)\,dx\,dy
$$